# Julia macros: @__FILE__ @__LINE__ in macro

Tags: macros, julia

This code:

```julia
macro FL(message) 
    return @sprintf("%s:%d | %s", @__FILE__, @__LINE__, message) # line 2
end
println(@FL("m")) # line 4
```

prints `fl.jl:2 | m`. How can I make it print `fl.jl:4 | m`?

Comment: Hi @Rolf, I formatted you code in markdown. Please review it to ensure the meaning is preserved, given that line numbers are important here.

Comment: @phg In julia `#` marks start of comment, not`//`.
I suggest that you leave reformatting code to people who know the language -- though I do appreciate you did leave a comment for the asker.

Comment: @LyndonWhite I do know Julia. I just program in a lot of other languages, too ;) Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @phg ah yes, the good old [code-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching) problem. I know it well.

Comment: Hi @phg  thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

The following will work in the current Julia nightly:

```
macro FL(message) 
    return :(@sprintf("%s:%d | %s", $(string(__source__.file)), $(__source__.line), $(esc(message)))) # line 2
end
println(@FL("m")) # line 4
```

This was made possible by the following [implementation pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/21746). It is not possible in any officially released version, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately I don't get Julia nighly running. I get : CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options. I will try to find figure this out.

Comment: That's due to multiple LLVM versions loaded in the same process. IIRC there are open issues in Julia base and OpenCL.jl about it (not sure if any resolution).

Answer (score 3):

Though there may be more elegant ways to do this, if you don't want this to block your progress on other fronts, why not just pass the line number to the macro...

```
macro FL(message, line)
    return @sprintf("%s:%d | %s", @__FILE__, line, message)
end
println(@FL("m", @__LINE__))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Of course this is a solution. But I want to avoid this, especially because I want to add @__FILE__.

Comment: Then you can just add `@__FILE__` as an argument too.